# Converting XML Data web file to XLS file in python on linux

Tags: python, linux, excel

I'm beginner in python programming and i'm currently struglling to find a solution with my python script. Here is my issue,

I wrote a small script in python using python-excel modules ( xlwt,xlrd and xlutils). This script is using an xls file that i converted from a xml data web file manualy by opening it and save it as a xls when i have done the local test.

But as i'm installing my script on a linux server side, i need to make this conversion automatically by using a python script but a i can't figure out how to do it ?

I looked over xlutils but i didn't find a way to make it.

By the way the purpose of this script is to compare 2 xls files and create a new update xls file.
Is it possible to do it with python ? or maybe directly on linux command tool?

Thanks
N.B: sorry for my poor english.

Comment: you should really give it a try and come back with code and problems you have, to extract data from a web page look for python `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`

Comment: @Guy I know some of basic with BS4 but as the xml is huge i wanted to avoid parsing this xml...